# Checkbox in my tree menu cannot be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I build a tree menu with a checkbox. Then I use Jquery to make item could be hide.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {
      if ($(this).children().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_minus.gif)").children().show();
      } else {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_plus.gif)").children().hide();
      }
    }
    return false;
  }).css("cursor", "pointer").click();

  $("li:not(:has(ul))").css({
    "cursor": "default",
    "list-style-image": "none"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TreeMenu">
  <div class="section">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test1" />detail1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test2" aria-checked="mixed" aria-controls="test3" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked" />detail2
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test3" aria-checked="true" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked" />detail2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "test1" checkbox can be checked, but "test2" and "test3" are no react when I click. How to solve the problem?

Comment: They actually react, but this code `onclick="this.checked=!this.checked"` reset immediately their value when clicked. Remove it and you will be able to click them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things in your code are not right.
On html why are you using `onclick="this.checked=!this.checked"` you can delete this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TreeMenu">
  <div class="section">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test1" />detail1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test2" aria-checked="mixed" aria-controls="test3" />detail2
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test3" aria-checked="true" />detail2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the other is on the script. You are always returning false on all the li element, also inside the checkbox. You don't have to rturn false, because li has no default action, but if you want to mantain you must put inside the `if (this == e.target)`

```
$("li:has(ul)").click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {
      if ($(this).children().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_minus.gif)").children().show();
      } else {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_plus.gif)").children().hide();
      }
    return false;
    }

  }).css("cursor", "pointer").click();
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I delete return false and my checkbox can be check.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to add onclick event on checkbox input.
- Detail2 and detail2.2 are not checkable because you return false when click is triggered.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {
      if ($(this).children().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_minus.gif)").children().show();
      } else {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_plus.gif)").children().hide();
      }
    }
   // return false;
  }).css("cursor", "pointer").click();

  $("li:not(:has(ul))").css({
    "cursor": "default",
    "list-style-image": "none"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TreeMenu">
  <div class="section">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test1" />detail1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test2" aria-checked="mixed" aria-controls="test3" />detail2
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test3" aria-checked="true" />detail2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `click` events for elements `$("li:has(ul)")`. Keep only one click listener.

As well you are using `return false` in the `click` callback function, which is preventing the checkbox to be checked.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {
      if ($(this).children().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_minus.gif)").children().show();
      } else {
        $(this).css("list-style-image", "url(http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/image/style/list_plus.gif)").children().hide();
      }
    }
    //   return false;
  }).css("cursor", "pointer").click();

  $("li:not(:has(ul))").css({
    "cursor": "default",
    "list-style-image": "none"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TreeMenu">
  <div class="section">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test1" />detail1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test2" aria-checked="mixed" aria-controls="test3" />detail2
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" id="test3" aria-checked="true" />detail2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```